# What is the better way of saying "a few dozens of seconds"?

Tags: grammar, academia

I want to say "wait for about 30 to 40 seconds and then execute the command", in an academic context. I'm using this sentence now but I think it is not good.

> after a few dozens of seconds activate the link, by executing the command below.

How should I say this?

Comment: How accurate do you want this to be? Because "few" is widely open to interpretation.

Comment: to wait approximately 30-40 seconds. That's how it would be written.

Comment: 12, 24, 36… Why not say 40 seconds?

Comment: @Stan The OP said about 30 to 40 seconds. How can that not be clear?

Comment: 'Dozen' is more informal, not more educated-sounding.

Comment: Just curious - what happens if they execute the command without waiting?  Or, are they stuck waiting until they can execute the command?

Comment: 30 seconds is "half a minute". 30 to 40 seconds is "around half a minute".

Comment: @Lambie Under the right set of circumstances, accepting that kind of precision and clarity have gotten peopled killed. Is it 30 or … 40?

Comment: At least in my idiolect "dozens of" cannot be used with a number or other quantifier. It needs to be "a few dozen seconds". (That's not addressing the question of whether this is a likely collocation or not - as others have said, I don't think it is).

Comment: A few dozen x is adjectival.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to give a specific range of seconds, then do so:

> After 30–40 seconds, activate the link by executing the command below.

Trying to use **about** when you actually want to give details is defeating the purpose. In academic settings particularly, you want to be more precise.

Instructions on how to microwave frozen pizza, for instance, typically say something like "Cook for 12—15 minutes." A number range is used, not **about** or **around**.

(Note that en dashes should be used with number ranges rather than hyphens.)

Answer (score 0):

I would volunteer a bigger division of time.

"**Could you wait about a minute?**" might be a useable way to express your thought. A minute (or two) isn't immediate, but suggests something brief.

It depends on the adverse consequences of executing the command too early or repeatedly if the command is made prematurely. Your requirement for the time interval is vague as stated.

While the time period may be slightly longer than intended, waiting tends to overemphasize the time. This might be better than to suggest a shorter one if you are not sure of your precision or required accuracy.

You are giving a procedure to an individual to follow. Academic level means little in terms of giving clear instructions. Desire for literary achievement over clarity is misplaced effort.

Comment: OP said 30 to 40 seconds!  Who knows.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I appreciate the person who like myself seems to consider any answer to this question inappropriate on a site aimed at linguists. I doubt it would be well received on ELL.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for your time and comment. I enjoy reading your thoughts.

Comment: Actually @EdwinAshworth word choice, and particularly word choice related to time and translating numerical data into words is a big linguistic problem. [This paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0004370205000998?via%3Dihub) and others in the NLG field shows this. Although this question is quite simple, answers to it can broaden understanding.

Comment: @Pam Not when they're at the 'This is idiomatic; this isn't' level (ie no deeper discussion) when a junior-school child would be expected to know this. And sadly, this is what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

"Wait about 30 seconds" is perfectly normal-sounding; so why are you worried about it?

"A few dozens of seconds" is decidedly un-idiomatic, and clumsy; so why would you use it?

I think you answered your own question.